# How to use a timer with a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, timer

I am new to dictionaries and found that they can be quite useful. I have a c# server console that accepts multiple client connections. Each time a client connects, it is added to the server dictionary. I am currently using .net 3.5 (and wont be upgrading any time soon) and am using a dictionary that is not thread safe nor static. Clients generally exit on their own, but I need to implement a fail-safe. I want to use a timer to close connection after 5 minutes if the client doesn't exit on their own. After the connection is closed, that item needs to be removed from the dictionary. How would I make my dictionary and timer work to achieve this? I am stuck and have exhausted my resources.
I am using "_clientSockets.Remove(current)" to close connections

Below is a code snippet of what I currently have for a dictionary and timer:

```
private static Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
        private static Object thisLock = new Object();
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            aTimer.Interval = 1000 * 60 * 5;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program.");
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            Console.ReadLine();

        Dictionary<int, DateTime> ServDict = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();

            ServDict.Add(9090, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5));
            ServDict.Add(9091, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5));
            ServDict.Add(9092, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5));
            ServDict.Add(9093, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5));
            ServDict.Add(9094, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5));
            Console.WriteLine("Time List");

                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, DateTime> time in ServDict)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Port = {0}, Time in 5 = {1}",
                        time.Key, time.Value);
                }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {           
            Console.WriteLine("The trigger worked, The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        }
```

Comment: probably I'm missing something, but it seems you should have a new dictionary, whenever a new client connect you add a new entry with a new timer as a KEY and the client as a value. when the timer fire you retrieve the client from the dictionary using the source of the event for the key. and disconnect the client. Note: my are just supposition and are just an idea that I hope will help you to get on the right path before someone answer with something right/tested

Comment: sounds like you're trying to build Microsoft Enterprise Libraries caching. Stop doing it - use EL5.0 caching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your method, there is no way of associating a particular key in the dictionary with a specific timeout. You would have to "poll" your dictionary every n number of seconds (where n is how much you can miss the 5 minute mark by) and check to see how long it has been since you recieved data.

A better solution may be to wrap your clients in a class (and just hold a list, you probably don't even need a dictionary)? In this case, each instance of the class can hold a "Timeout" timer that elapses after 5 minutes and invokes the close connection function. The same event handler could also raise an event that the class holding all the clients registers for so it can remove it from the active list.

Whenever data is recieved, the client class would reset the timer. This could easily be achieved by using a System.Threading.Timer and calling Change(dueTime, period) on it.

Something like the following should work:

```
public class Client
{
  public event Action<Client> Timeout;
  System.Threading.Timer timeoutTimer;

  public Client()
  {
    timeoutTimer = new Timer(timeoutHandler, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
  }

  public void onDataRecieved()
  {
     timeoutTimer.Change(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
  }

  public void timeoutHandler(object data)
  {
     CloseConnection();
     if (Timeout != null)
        Timeout(this);
  }
}

class Program
{
   List<Client> connectedClients = new List<Client>

   void OnConnected(object clientData)
   {
      Client newClient = new Client();
      newClient.Timeout += ClientTimedOut;
      connectedClients.Add(newClient);
   }

   void ClientTimedOut(Client sender)
   {
      connectedClients.Remove(sender);
   }
}
```